# Structure padding of vectors in C++

Tags: c++, vector, struct

Is there any structure padding of vectors in C++, as there is with structs?

In other words, would Code A take up the same amount of memory as Code B if I were to insert however many values into the vectors, or less?

[image]

Comment: On common systems `struct A` will have size 8, so the total memory usage for large vector will be greater for `A`

Comment: Code should be posted as text, not images.

Comment: A `struct` doesn't change just because you put it in a vector. If it is padded outside the vector then it will be padded inside the vector.

Comment: Note that if you are choosing between these *only* on the metric of which leads to a smaller allocation, you are choosing poorly. The additional complexity of ensuring that `vec` and `vec2`'s elements remain in sync is not worth the memory savings. The only situation where it is valid is when the allocation for `std::vector<A>` would be larger than your address space, but `std::vector<int>` + `std::vector<short>` wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

No: an array of `T` takes up `sizeof(T)` bytes per element (plus a constant overhead if the array is dynamically allocated), and `std::vector<T>` acts like `T[]` in this regard (albeit with somewhat higher overhead due to knowing its size and capacity).  So any padding is that of the `struct`—including *tail* padding after the last member that is always included in `sizeof`.